# SQL table schema check with Jmeter

Tags: sql, jmeter

I'm trying to test SQL tables schema in my dev/test server is inline with my mapping document, like number of columns, data type and length, is null property of columns etc in a table using JMeter. here is the sample query.
'

```
select TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,IS_NULLABLE 
from information_schema.columns 
Where table_name = 'abc'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='STAGING'
```

I want to compare the output of the above query with my predefined schema to make sure schema is inline with my mapping document. tried putting the output of the above query in response assertion ***patterns to test***, but its not working. is there a possibility to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of comparing the database schemas is a little bit weird, I would rather go for something like [Liquibase diff](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html) or [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)

---

Whatever...

If you add a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the JDBC Request sampler and put the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) code into its "Script" area:

```
log.info('-------------------------')
log.info(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
log.info('-------------------------')
```

you will see that there will be a blank line before last `-------------------------`

[image]

You need to ensure that the same blank line is in [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) pattern:

[image]